# Owin and switch user

Tags: c#, .net, owin

Having an issue with Owin (pretty new to this).

Basically, we have a windows desktop application which runs Owin and listens for requests on

```
static string baseAddress = "https://+:4443/";


_server = WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: baseAddress);
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

using (ProcessIcon pi = new ProcessIcon())
{
    pi.Display();

    // Make sure the application runs!
    Application.Run();
}
```

The application runs on start up and is always listening.. all working great.

The issue is when "Switch User" happens.
When the new user logs in they are presented with

```
Failed to listen on prefix 'https://+:4443/' because it conflicts with an existing registration on the machine.
```

I understand the reason why this is occurring, however, struggling to find a nice solution to resolve this without it getting messy detecting events etc..
Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Normally, if the application isn't user-bound, you should choose to build a windows-service

Comment: If you find it difficult to create a service, try `topshelf`, it transforms a console application into a windows service, it's free (nuget)  and real easy to debug and deploy.

Comment: Thanks stephan, i believe that the application is user-bound ( how can we check? ) we need it to be running as a windows application as it sits in the task bar and will be used for other things

Answer (score 1):

Well, if the user needs to interact with the application it is user-bound. So, in your case a service wouldn't be applicable, well; for the user interaction part.

The problem here is that the port is already in use by the first user that sign in. Because the application is still running, a new user that starts the application will encounter this problem

If you are hosting a web-application, you have a couple of options:

- Host in IIS: IIS is a windows service suited to host web applications with application pools etc. It is always running a single instance of your application
- Split logic in 2 applications and create a service: In this scenario you'll have a windows service which does all the incomming web-app stuff and another one which interact with the user. The application that interacts with the user can communicate with the web-app through the standard http calls.
- Subscribe to different ports for different instances. This could be a user setting for example. This provides the fastest fix in your case but might lead to issueses later on.